# Получится ли превратить программу в exe?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image: много файлов]

Можно ли превратить мою многофайловую программу, в exe?

Я преобразовывал pyqt5 файл в exe, только когда файлик был один.. А тут их десятки, но главный это main.

Comment: вы попробовали и что-то не получается ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файлы импортируют друг друга, то не должно быть никаких проблем. В `pyinstaller` или другой сборщик в .exe передайте именно главный файл